# Xamarin Firebase DeleteAsync

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

I am having trouble deleting items from my Firebase Database on my Xamarin Android App.

I am getting a 400 (Bad Request) error

Delete Method:

```
private async void RemovePost(string ActivityID)
{
    var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseURL);
    await firebase.Child("posts").Child(ActivityID).DeleteAsync();

    var intent = new Intent(mContext, typeof(MyProfileActivity));
    mContext.StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Model:

```
public class Post
{
    public string ActivityID { get; set; }

    public string OwnerID { get; set; }

    public string ActivityTitle { get; set; }

    public string ActivitySport { get; set; }

    public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ActivityTime { get; set; }

    public string ActivityTown { get; set; }

    public string ActivityAddress { get; set; }

    public string ActivityPhone { get; set; }

    public string ActivityEmail { get; set; }

    public string ActivityDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Firebase Database Table:
[image]

Note the activity id I am passing to the `RemovePost` method is "0"

Comment: Are your requests suppose to be Authenticated?

Comment: No they do not have to be Authenticated, all I want to do is delete the item from the database which matches the id that I pass to it

Comment: What firebase library are you using?

Comment: Firebase.Xamarin v0.3.6

Comment: Does `await firebase.Child("posts").Child("KiG7ju8CsDfGW3eSBIn").DeleteAsync();` work? Because based on the provided table, this should delete that record.

Comment: No I tried that and it does not delete anything from the database

Comment: Just tried that again and I was able to get it working,by changing it to "-KiG7ju8CsDfGW3eSBIn"

Comment: Ok i did not notice the dash at the beginning in the image, but yeah it should work once you provide the correct key for the child node. That is how the library and rest api works

Comment: Any idea how I could get the correct key for post matching the Activity ID I pass?

Comment: So at least now we know that it is possible to remove a record from the database. now to see if we can satisfy your requirements of getting a record based on a child property

Comment: Well why don't you make the activityid the key when saving the record to the database in the first place? Short of that you would have to load all records, then traverse them for the one that matches your filter and then use it's key to remove it from the databse

Comment: That worked, thanks very much Nkosi!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well why don't you make the `ActivityId` the key when saving the record to the database in the first place?

```
var post = new Post {
    ActivityId = 0,
    //...other properties populated
}

var record = await firebase
    .Child("posts")
    .Child(post.ActivityId)
    .PostAsync(post));

var posts = await firebase
    .Child("posts")
    .OnceAsync<Post>();

foreach (var item in posts) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} post has id {item.Object.ActivityId}");
}

await firebase.Child("posts").Child(post.ActivityID).DeleteAsync();
```

That way when querying records you can query on a known key

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
await firebase.Child("posts").Child(ActivityID)
```

Will try to match the ActivityID to the root of the node which in your case is the value **`KiG7ju8CsDfGW3eSBIn`**

Try changing your firebase delete call to something like this:

```
await firebase.Child("posts").OrderBy("ActivityID").EqualTo(ActivityID).DeleteAsync();
```

***UPDATE***

Try this so you can debug. Put a break point and run over the calls to see what's the result.

```
//Get the record(s). Can be more than one if ActivityID value is repeated.
var posts = await firebase
    .Child("posts")
    .OrderBy("ActivityID")
    .EqualTo("0")
    .OnceAsync<Post>();

// Select only the first one
var firstPost = posts.FirstOrDefault();

// send to delete this
await firebase
    .Child("posts")
    .Child(firstPost?.Key)
    .DeleteAsync();
```

Comment: This line gives me a new error: {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Try getting the record first, don't do the delete part  `firebase.Child("posts").OrderBy("ActivityID").EqualTo(ActivityID)` and debug to see if you have access to the record. Also tell me what's the nuget package you are using

Comment: I am using Firebase.Xamarin v0.3.6 and when I use that line I get a Firebase.Xamarin.Database.Query.FilterQueryobject, I am trying to dig into that to see if it is my post object but I haven't been able to find it yet

Comment: @CathalO'Donnell made an update to the post so you can try and specially debug.

Comment: When I try to run that code I am getting an exception error: "400 (Bad Request)", it crashes on the first line

Comment: I see ActivityID is of type string. Change the 0 for "0" in the first line. not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: No I tried that already and unfortunately I am still getting the same error